# Finding some of two dict's key items ignoring the item with lowest value dict

Tags: python, math

I have list containing dictionaries like this

```
[{u'itemcode': 1, u'cost': 5, u'type': u'train', u'name': u'percy'},
{u'itemcode': 2, u'cost': 10, u'type': u'train', u'name': u'Caron'},
{u'itemcode': 3, u'cost': 12, u'type': u'train', u'name': u'thameslink'},
{u'itemcode': 6, u'cost': 15, u'type': u'car', u'name': u'Ford'},]
```

I want sum of same type of items cost but ignoring the lowest value of the 3 or more  same type.

```
[{u'itemcode': 4, u'cost': 20.5, u'type': u'car', u'name': u'volvo'},
{u'itemcode': 5, u'cost': 25, u'type': u'car', u'name': u'tesla'},
{u'itemcode': 6, u'cost': 15, u'type': u'car', u'name': u'Ford'}]
```

for this set the total should be 45.5 but what comes out is `40`
I am trying to put togther same items with cost:

```
    types = {}
    selected_types = []
    current_item_cost = []
    last_item_type = None
    for item in self._deserialize():
        # if item["type"] not in types:
            current_item_cost.append(item["cost"])
            types[item["type"]] = current_item_cost

    print types
```

but this adds all costs in each type

so for 3 trains, I'd imagine sum should be 22 ignoring the item with itemcode 1 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below collects costs for same type items, then prints the total sum removing the lowest one if the length is 3 or greater.

```
#!python3
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'itemcode': 1, 'cost': 5, 'type': 'train', 'name': 'percy'},
        {'itemcode': 2, 'cost': 10, 'type': 'train', 'name': 'Caron'},
        {'itemcode': 3, 'cost': 12, 'type': 'train', 'name': 'thameslink'},
        {'itemcode': 6, 'cost': 15, 'type': 'car', 'name': 'Ford'}]

types = defaultdict(list)
for datum in data:
    types[datum['type']].append(datum['cost'])

for item,costs in types.items():
    print(f'type: {item} total: {sum(sorted(costs)[1:]) if len(costs) >= 3 else sum(costs)}')
```

```
#!python2
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{u'itemcode': 1, u'cost': 5, u'type': u'train', u'name': u'percy'},
        {u'itemcode': 2, u'cost': 10, u'type': u'train', u'name': u'Caron'},
        {u'itemcode': 3, u'cost': 12, u'type': u'train', u'name': u'thameslink'},
        {u'itemcode': 6, u'cost': 15, u'type': u'car', u'name': u'Ford'}]

types = defaultdict(list)
for datum in data:
    types[datum[u'type']].append(datum[u'cost'])

for item,costs in types.items():
    total = sum(sorted(costs)[1:]) if len(costs) >= 3 else sum(costs)
    print u'type: {} total: {}'.format(item,total)
```

Output:

```
type: train total: 22
type: car total: 15
```

Comment: seems to be something wrong  when I tried to add 3 items with these costs `[20.5, 20, 15]` updated in description as well

Comment: why are you doing this `costs[1:]` it means do not consider the first item, when I do not wanted to consider the lowest item, this needs to be applied `costs.pop(costs.index(min(costs)))` somehow

Comment: `sorted(costs)[1:]`?

Comment: Or skip the (potentially expensive) sort/slice, and just do `total = sum(costs)` `if len(costs) >= 3: total -= min(costs)`. `O(n)` overall, where involving sorting makes it `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @Ciasto There was a bug as Mykola pointed out. I didn’t catch it since the example generated an already sorted scenario. Fixed post.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = [{u'itemcode': 1, u'cost': 5, u'type':           u'train', u'name': u'percy'},
{u'itemcode': 2, u'cost': 10, u'type':                 u'train', u'name': u'Caron'},
{u'itemcode': 3, u'cost': 12, u'type':                u'train', u'name': u'thameslink'},
{u'itemcode': 6, u'cost': 15, u'type': u'car',     u'name': u'Ford'},]
li=[]
length= len(d)
for i in range(length-1):
    dic = d[i]
    li.append(dic[u'cost'])
lowest = min(li)
li.remove(lowest)
print(sum(li))
```

Comment: @E.Zeytinci: Did you mean to comment on the question? Because that comment you made doesn't apply to *answers*.

Comment: You're right @ShadowRanger. I deleted my previous comment. Actually, I wanted to write this : While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.